# Encoded unicode characters lost

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, unicode, request, urlencode

I submitting

```
MyApp.aspx?url=http://product.cn.china.cn/selling-leads/%C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF/
```

url as GET request to my ASP.NET application. The Chinese characters are encoded in url. I am trying to read URL parameter value with

```
httpRequest.Params["url"]
```

and get result like this

```
http://product.cn.china.cn/selling-leads/ȼ�����/
```

The encoded part is lost. Where is the problem?

Comment: What are the actual characters you are expecting?

Comment: The same Url which was submitted. I am losing the part %C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF

Comment: I meant, what are the *Chinese* characters you are expecting? :)

Comment: I do not expect anything. I need to save exact URL into database which user submitted. I want to get http://product.cn.china.cn/selling-leads/%C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF in code behind of asp.net app.

Comment: OK, the answer that I updated yesterday shows you how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the characters have been encoded correctly in the URL?

If I URL enode `公共汽車`, I get `%E5%85%AC%E5%85%B1%E6%B1%BD%E8%BB%8A`

If I pass in `%E5%85%AC%E5%85%B1%E6%B1%BD%E8%BB%8A` as a query parameter it works fine, but doesn't with your string, `%C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF`.

If I try decoding your string with an [online URL encoder/decoder](http://urldecoder.net/), it also doesn't work, likewise if I try `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`.

So I think the problem is that the string you are submitting has been encoded incorrectly.

** **UPDATE** **

Upon closer inspection it appears that the characters in your URL string are GBK encoded (the page you linked to also says the character set in use is GBK).

I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but if you want the URL parameter in another encoding you will need to convert from GBK to that other encoding.

** **UPDATE** **

OK, I think I've got it :)

It looks like ASP.NET is decoding the URL using the wrong encoding. You can force ASP.NET to decode requests as GBK by adding this to your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization requestEncoding="gbk" />
</system.web>
```

If for some reason you don't want to do that, then you will need to parse and decode the raw URL yourself:

```
// TODO: Grab this from Request.RawUrl
string urlParam = "%C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF";

// Source encoding is GBK
Encoding gbk = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk");

string decodedParam = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlParam, gbk);
```

decodedParam will now contain what you want, `燃气灶具` ("gas stove", I think :)

Comment: The URL is taken from Chrome browser while navigating, so it can't be incorectlly encoded. Moreover try to paste this url in browser and web page will be opened correctly http://product.cn.china.cn/selling-leads/%C8%BC%C6%F8%D4%EE%BE%DF/

Comment: URLs are usually encoded in UTF-8, and I guess ASP.NET assumes this.

Comment: GB-encoded URIs are incompatible with IRI, so won't display nicely in modern browsers (as `http://product.cn.china.cn/selling-leads/公共汽車`) and won't give you the search engine advantage of having keywords in the path. I'd strongly advise moving to UTF-8-encoded URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem with hebrew

You have to use HttpUtility.UrlDecode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

Like this

```
dim str=HttpUtility.UrlEncode("the string that add to the url")
```

(And of course to send the str in the url)

And in the receive page use this

```
dim temp as string=HttpUtility.UrlDecode(httpRequest.Params["url"] , System.Text.Encoding.Default())
```

You can do it in javascript too

`escape(value)` is a function to encode the text

and you can use on server side like this:

```
dim temp as string=HttpUtility.UrlDecode(httpRequest.Params["url"] , System.Text.Encoding.Default())
```