# Why all my right to left letters have been corrupted

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, encoding, arabic

I have  web application solutions , some pages contain `arabic letters` ,After moving the solutions to another pc , all the arabic letters converted to corrupted letters ,something like that :

```
ÈíÇäÇÊ ÇáØÇáÈ
```

---

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076538/encoded-unicode-characters-lost. It may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not corrupted. VS.NET based on the current culture of the OS (windows-1256), shows those letters correctly. If the `regional settings` of the new system is not configured for  windows-1256, you will see the above letters. You have 2 options here:

- Change the `regional settings` of the windows to Arabic (Windows-1256)

[image]

- Or convert your files to UTF-8 with signature this way:

FixWindows1256

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"));  
File.WriteAllText(path, data, Encoding.UTF8);
```