# writing arabic numbers Into Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net-2010, arabic

I have a little but headbrick problem which consists on assigning arabic numbers into string.

What I try to write into my program is like below :

```
Dim TestDebt As Double = 4456.438
Dim TestString As String = FormatCurrency(TestDebt)

If TestString <> "ر.س.‏4,456.44" Then
    Check_System_params = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

But into my Visual Studio IDE, It is Written like :
[image: MisSpelled Caracters]

Which setting should I change to be able to write the desired string (without the  `?` caracters)

Thank you

Comment: Interesting question. The question marks are Arabic commas, right?

Comment: one is comma and the second is a period.

Comment: This easiest way is to replace them with "" in both members of the in-equation and makes the comparison. Otherwise, I think you need to make a function that will convert the period and the comma into an ASCII comma and period on both ends of the comparison.

Comment: I think it is an encoding issue. Beside that, I want to avoid the fact of replacing or converting functions.

Comment: Can you do a `chrw` on the question marks?

Comment: When I Copy the  `?` into another plance in the IDE it is correctly shown `,`  or `.`

Comment: Apparently, VB.NET IDE does not recognize the Arabic comma and the period. 

Actually, that is quite clear because the char in between and after your currency letters itself is an actual ASCII period.

The only workaround is to make a function that would replace your question marks with ASCII period and comma.

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25511014/298573

Comment: @VahidN : I am interested in the second solution `Or convert your files to UTF-8 with signature this way`. How to do that ? in Which files should I add those lines ? thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is an issue of Editor I did as follow ( I convert Strings to Windows 1256 and don't make attention at what is written in the IDE) :

```
Public Shared Function Utf8_TO_1256(ByVal read As String) As String
    Dim rawBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(read)
    Dim converted As New  String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetChars(rawBytes))
Return converted.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: yes, After All, what I do is pass the strings with the `?` carracters to the function and returns it to sth clear without the `?`